# Machine learning (KNeighborsRegressor) Train score = 1

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to understand the outcome of this model. What I don't understand is why the score train is always one. I understand that this type of behavior is due to overfitting. However, I have already modified several hyper parameters and I have not been able to modify this behavior.

I am using 16 features and a dataset divided into 12,000 training data and 3,000 test data. The code that I'm using to validate my model is :

```
model_KNR = KNeighborsRegressor(metric = 'manhattan', n_neighbors = 3, weights = 'distance', leaf_size = 1,n_jobs=-1,algorithm = 'ball_tree')

model_KNR.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred_KNR = model_KNR.predict(x_test)
error_KNR, error_original = compute_error(y_pred_KNR, y_real, y_test)

N, train_score, val_score = learning_curve(model_KNR, x_train, y_train, train_sizes = np.linspace(.01,1,10), cv=cv, scoring='r2',n_jobs=-1)

plt.plot(N,train_score.mean(axis=1), label = 'train')
plt.plot(N, val_score.mean(axis=1), label = 'validation')
plt.xlabel('Train sizes')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
print("Average error         :%.2f"%np.mean(error_KNR),"m")
print("Quality of prediction :%.2f"%r2_score(y_pred_KNR, y_test))
print("")
```

The result is :

```
Accuracy              :0.94 (+/- 0.01)
Average error         :0.22 m
Quality of prediction :0.94
```

[image]

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, when you use `weights=distance`, your samples are weighted by the inverse of their distances to the query point. If the query point is inside the training set, the closest point is itself and the distance is $0$. When inverted, this becomes infinity while the other closest samples' weights are finite. When averaged, other points have no effect and the query point is predicted as itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had doubts about it, so I used gridsearchCV to find the best hyperparameters. Now that I have modified the way to get the weights, the resus are change and they make more sense. Thank you very much